# Magento 2: The value of attribute “is_new” must be set

Tags: magento2

Whenever I try to save a category I get The value of attribute "is_new" must be set. How can I solve that?
This issue occur after update magento version from magento 2.0.9 CE to magento 2.1.1 CE.

Thanks!

Comment: You have created any custom category attributes ?

Comment: No , don't create any custom category attributes @S H Patel

Comment: Tx @S H Patel , your right , my issue resolved.

Comment: my comment is use full for you, mark comment as use full.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be treated as a bug, check this [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7232) on github.
You have to ways to omit it:

- first is to change value of `is_required` property of your attribute from `1` to `0`.
- second option is setting empty default value - ' '. Then there is no exception, but this default value as empty is set in db.

Don't know which one is better, it depends on your needs.